# Passing data with segue through navigationController

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

I'm trying to push data from one viewController to another. I've connected a viewController to another ViewController's navigationController and then set the identifier to `"showItemSegue"`. I get an error in these two lines:

```
var detailController = segue.destinationViewController as ShowItemViewController
detailController.currentId = nextId!
```

Image illustration:

[image]

The code:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    nextId = itemArray?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("objectId") as? NSString

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showItemSegue", sender: self)

}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if (segue.identifier == "showItemSegue") {
        var detailController = segue.destinationViewController as ShowItemViewController
        detailController.currentId = nextId!
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the full error message

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The destination view controller of the segue is the `UINavigationController`.  You need to ask it for its top view controller to get to the real destination view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showItemSegue" {
        let navController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let detailController = navController.topViewController as! ShowItemViewController
        detailController.currentId = nextId!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution seems to work fine with swift 3

Comment: Awesome! This helped me with modal dialogs that were embedded in a Navigation Controller - without a visible navigation bar - in order to have a navigation bar (+ back button) in the next segued view controller. Due to the rather complicated setup I was a bit anxious.. But it works fine :)

Comment: In messing around with this a little I found that if you create the segue between the two view controllers and bypass the navigation controller on the storyboard, then the code in the question works just fine, and you still have the back button presented in the buttonbar.  If you have the segue between the view controller and the navigation controller then the answer provided by @vacawama works perfectly and there is no back button provided in the buttonbar.  May just be a matter of preference.