# Passing data with segue through TabBarControllerController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segue

Try this one [Passing data with segue through navigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26951195/passing-data-with-segue-through-navigationcontroller) but I need one more step before `UITabBarController`

[image]

> ViewController->UITabBarController->UINavigationController->RestaurantTableViewController

The destination view controller of the segue is the `UITabBarController`. How can I get  the real destination `RestaurantTableViewController`:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == segueIdentifire() {
            let dcTabBar = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
            let dcNabBar = //i don't know what should i write here? 
            let dc = dcNabBar.topViewController as! RestaurantTableViewController
            dc.dcTitle = "Restaurant"

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the vc with `dcTabBar.viewControllers?[0]` (replace 0 with index) or just `dcTabBar.selectedViewController` if its the first tabbar item

Comment: could you  write **prepare** method ?

Comment: This is for the part you said you dont know what you should write, the other part seems correct already

Comment: let dc = dcNabBar.topViewController as! RestaurantTableViewController this line error throwing  
Value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'topViewController'

Comment: have you put `as! UINavigationController` ? I missed that

Comment: yes but if i put as! UINavigationController then **unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Comment: Have you try both of the code above? Also try to print `dcTabBar.viewControllers?` to see if it hold any object

Answer (score 0):

**See if it working for you:**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      if segue.identifier == "toTabController" {
        var tabBarC : UITabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController
        var desView: RestaurantTableViewController = tabBarC.viewControllers?.first as RestaurantTableViewController

        var caseIndex = overviewTableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
        var selectedCase = self.cases[caseIndex]

        desView.caseitem = selectedCase
      }
    }
```