# Passing parameter on Perform Segue returns nil

Tags: swift, parameter-passing

I have a splashscreen which is shown for 5 seconds. After this time I call another ViewController(VC_Products) programmatically with a seque and want to pass parameters, but my ViewController does not receive anything.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //here we set a timer to start after a given amount of seconds the ProductViewController
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timeToMoveOn), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}


@objc func timeToMoveOn() {

    //change root navigation controller
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.changeRootViewControllerToSWRevealViewController()

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "splashscreen_to_products", sender: self)

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "splashscreen_to_products") {

        if let vc: VC_Products = segue.destination as? VC_Products {
               vc.titleremote = "variableToPass"
        }

    }
}
```

In the VC_Products:

I have following:

```
var titleremote:String = ""
```

and it does not change to "variableToPass". Nothing happens! Why?

Maybe my seque is wrong?
[image]

UPDATE:

Seemed that changing rootview controller to SWRevealViewController was the cause why I could not pass parameters. I removed the SWrevealViewController and it worked. Somehow, I need the SWRevealViewController to have a left menu, but then I am not able to pass data. I wanted to load images from remote URL in splashscreen and pass them then to a VC_Products where the images are presented. This is not possible. I searched for two days finding a way to pass the image thorugh the SWRevealViewController, but without success. I will now go a different way and save the loaded image in the splashscreen to temporary folder and just load the images from there in the VC_Products. That is what I hate about iOS coding. Storyboard and the whole navigation between controllers is horrible as the layout constraints and debugging is in iOS. In Android it just works without any problems.

Comment: Add `print(type(of: segue.destination))` at the start of `prepare(for:sender:)` and tell us what it prints.

Comment: @vacawama: print(type(of: segue.destination)): UINavigationController

Comment: Ah, thought so.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/26951195/1630618

Comment: Added solution from link and still getting nil for titleremote!

Comment: Add `print(type(of: navController.topViewController))`.  You should see `VC_Products`.

Comment: Result: Optional<UIViewController> The more: Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x16175400> on <xxx.ViewController: 0x156360d0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: You need to set the class of your UIViewController in the Storyboard to VC_Products.

Comment: It is set to VC_Products. Maybe it is due to change of RootViewController. Take a look at the function timeToMoveOn(). First two lines lead to appdelegate:     func changeRootViewControllerToSWRevealViewController () {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RevealViewController")
        if let window = self.window{
            window.rootViewController = controller
        }
    }

Comment: Why are you doing that?  I thought you were trying to segue from the splash screen to VC_Products.  The swap moves your current viewController out of the window hierarchy, so you've pulled the rug out under your own feet.

Comment: Not based on my shit. Take a look at the pic. Above the NavigationController there is the SWRevealViewController. It is needed to have a kind of left menu and being able to swipe so the left menu is shown to user.

Comment: Thanks Bro! I removed the controller appDelegate.changeRootViewControllerToSWRevealViewController() and now it works, but I have somehow find another solution now to get left menu to work! Thanks for your effort!!! Great guy!

Comment: OK.  Good luck with the left menu.

Comment: If problem is solved, give answer or delete question please.

Comment: instead of changing root view controller use a navigation controller, once the new VC opens up you can pop the starting VC so its not in the stack

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get it. It only works without left menu. Cant get left menu to work otherwise. Thats what I hate about swift and iOS coding. Storyboard, Layout constraints, debuggin and navigation between VCs is horrible. I prefer Android way more. No problems with navigation, autolayout or debugging.